# why doesn't this jQuery code work in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The following code is used so when clicking 'enter' when focused in an input field within a form, it disables the standard submit button functionality.  Rather the javascript builds a new form and sends a post request to another page.  I am using this so that I can achieve a "form within a form" functionality.  The input field has its own submit button for which I have similar code to perform the post.

In firefox, this works perfectly; in IE hitting enter does nothing at all.  Here is the code:

```
//event handler for input field within standard form
$('#inputfield').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code==13){
        //suppress default submit functionality
        $('form').submit(function () {
            return false;
        });

        //...assemble some data here...

        var url_string = "...";

        var $form = $("<form method='POST'>").attr("action", url_string);
        $("<input type='hidden' name='body'>").attr("value",body).appendTo($form);

        $("<input type='hidden' name='title'>").attr("value",title).appendTo($form);

        //...create more form elements here...

        $form.appendTo("body");
        $form.submit();
    }
});
```

Any ideas why this isn't working in IE (I tried in IE 6,7 and 8)?

**Update:** just to elaborate on the problem: in firefox, the `$form.submit();` line at the end causes the jquery generated form to submit and the page to redirect. In IE nothing happens at all.  The keypress *does* fire in IE, its just that the form doesnt seem to get submitted.

Comment: Because IE blows? Sorry, had to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you try using the normal DOM submit method instead of jQuery's?

```
// instead of:
// $form.submit();
// try this:
$form[0].submit();
```

> ie gives me a javascript error: 0 is null or not an object..

Ok, that would suggest that your jQuery object is empty. It might be the appendTo which is doing strange things... try this:

```
$form = $form.appendTo("body");
$form.submit();
```

and if that doesn't work, put in these debugging lines:

```
alert($form.length);
$form.appendTo("body");
alert($form.length);
$form.submit();
```

---

**Ok, I've got it now:**

It's the line where you generate the form which is causing the problem. Change it to this:

```
var $form = $("<form></form>").attr({"action" : url_string, "method" : "POST"});
```

What you had should have worked, so that might be a bug in jQuery, I'm not sure.

Comment: it didn't work so I added the dubugging lines which alerted 0 for both (in firefox it alerts 1 for both)

Comment: Yes that worked! very strange indeed.  thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hey, I've put together this table which demonstrates the problem you had. View it in Firefox, then check out IE to see the difference. http://fisher.spadgos.com/stuff/jqueryConstructors.html

Answer (score 0):

The IE DOM is different and capturing the event is different than FF or Chrome.

```
var key;      
 if(window.event)
      key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
 else
      key = e.which; //firefox

if(key == 13)
      do a thing
```

Comment: unless I am misunderstanding you, like I mentioned in my update, the even is getting fired in IE so the issue is not with capturing the key event

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false at the end of the keypress event handler function. That signals the browser not to allow the "normal" result to occur after your custom function.